# Firefox: H.264 Video Support

Tags: firefox, video, html, h.264

I have Firefox 34 and `OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems v1.1` addon installed and enabled.

The problem is that Firefox can not play H.264 video. I used [this page](http://www.html5videoplayer.net/html5video/mp4-h-264-video-test/) for testing and here is the screenshot:

[image: h264]

Also, I tried to test my browser using https://www.youtube.com/html5 and it does not detect H.264 as well:

[image]

Am I the only one who has this problem? Why does Cisco H.264 codec does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Found answer [here](http://andreasgal.com/2014/10/14/openh264-now-in-firefox/):

> **Note**: Firefox currently uses OpenH264 only for WebRTC and not for the  tag, because OpenH264 does not yet support the high
>   profile format frequently used for streaming video. We will reconsider
>   this once support has been added.